# passing values to google.maps.LatLng

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have an array and I want to pass its values to a path to draw a polygon

```
var coords = new Array("25.1, 66", "25.5, 65", "21.3, 67");
```

regardless the coordinates numbers, how can i pass this pattern "x, y" as in the array above to google.maps.LatLng

```
  var triangleCoords = [ 
            new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0]),
             new google.maps.LatLng(coords[1]),
              new google.maps.LatLng(coords[2]),

  ];

  // Construct the polygon
  // Note that we don't specify an array or arrays, but instead just
  // a simple array of LatLngs in the paths property
  draw = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "#FF0000",
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
```

Comment: `LatLng` always needs two arguments - Latitude and Longitude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0])` you can do `new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0].split(',')[0],coords[0].split(',')[1])`.

However, since that's doing the split twice, I'd probably pull it out into a function - something like this:

```
function createLatLng(coordString) {
     var a = coordString.split(',');
     return new google.maps.LatLng(a[0],a[1]);
}

var triangleCoords = [ 
       createLatLng(coords[0]),
      ....
];
```

For extra credit, you can then use a for loop:

```
   var triangleCoords = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
      triangleCoords[i] = createLatLng(coords[i]);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var coords = new Array("25.1, 66", "25.5, 65", "21.3, 67");
var triangleCoords = [];
for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
 var pos = coords[i].split(",");
 var loc = new google.maps.LatLng(pos[0], pos[1]);
  triangleCoords.push(loc);
}
```